# Sendgrid API integration with Symfony2

Tags: symfony, sendgrid

I'm trying to integrate my app with SendGrid API [documentation](https://sendgrid.com/docs/API_Reference/Web_API_v3/Marketing_Campaigns/contactdb.html) using their [php library](https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-php/blob/master/USAGE.md#contactdb).

I installed it using composer (composer.json)

```
"require": {
    ...
    "sendgrid/sendgrid": "2.0.5",
    "sendgrid/php-http-client": "3.4"
}
```

Created a service (services.yml):

```
    sendgrid_service:
    class: AppBundle\Services\SendGridApiIntegration
    arguments: ['%sendgrid_api_key%', '%sendgrid_api_user%']
```

Service:

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Services;

use SendGrid;

class SendGridApiIntegration
{
    private $api_key;
    private $api_user;

    public function __construct($api_user, $api_key)
    {
        $this->api_user = $api_user;
        $this->api_key = $api_key;
    }


    public function testSendGrid()
    {
//        \SendGrid::register_autoloader();
//        $sg = new \SendGrid($this->api_user, $this->api_key);
        $sg = new \SendGrid($this->api_key);
        $request_body = json_decode('{
          "name": "pet",
          "type": "text"
        }');
        $response = $sg->client->contactdb()->custom_fields()->post($request_body);
        echo $response->statusCode();
        echo $response->body();
        echo $response->headers();
    }
}
```

I get the following error:

```
Notice: Undefined property: SendGrid::$client
```

I can't get it working and don't know what to do next.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code and the [documentation](https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-php/blob/master/USAGE.md#contactdb) is relevant to the latest version of SendGrid PHP SDK. You should install the latest version to make it work.

```
composer require sendgrid/sendgrid ~5.1
```